# How do I put numbers right aligned?

Tags: sas, datastep

How do I put numbers right aligned in a SAS data step?

```
data _null_;

  num =    1; put num=6.0;
  num =   10; put num=6.0;
  num =  100; put num=6.0;

run;
```

This data step puts

```
num=1
num=10
num=100
```

What I have wanted (and expected) was that it would put

```
num=     1
num=    10
num=   100
```

When I use the `Zw.d` format, the numbers are "correctly" right aligned, yet with the dreaded 0 padding.

Comment: This is going to work for the log and most text outputs, but likely not for an RTF, PDF and/or Excel file. So YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that pesky `=` sign you have in the put statement.  It throws off the logic for how the `PUT` statement aligns variables.

See this aligns the variables:

```
data _null_;
  num =    1; put  num 6.;
  num =   10; put  num 6.;
  num =  100; put  num 6.;
run;
```

like this:

```
     1
    10
   100
```

So if you want the `num=` to be in the log, you have to print that separately

```
data _null_;
  num =    1; put "num=" num 6.;
  num =   10; put "num=" num 6.;
  num =  100; put "num=" num 6.;
run;
```

Produces this:

```
num=     1
num=    10
num=   100
```